# React derivated state not updated properly

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I want to develop a tabs component in React. When I try to close an element and assign the active state to the previous or the next tab my **setFiles** method updates the files array properly but when the context is reloaded the derivated state **openedFiles** is not using the correct files state.

This is the code I have:

**context-provider.tsx**

```
const IdeEmulatorContextProvider: React.FC<{children: React.ReactNode}> = ({children}) => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<IdeFile[]>([]);
  const openedFiles = files.filter((element: IdeFile) => element.opened);
  
  const selectFileHandler = (event: any) => {
    // ...
  };

  const openFileInTab = (file: IdeFile) => {
    // ...
  };

  const closeTab = (name: string) => {
    setFiles((currentFiles: IdeFile[]) => {
      let indexToUpdate: number;

      const newFiles = currentFiles.map((element, index) => {
        if (name === element.name) {
          indexToUpdate = index;
          return {
            ...element,
            opened: false,
            active: false
          };
        } else {
          return element;
        }
      });

      if (indexToUpdate! >= 1) {
        newFiles[indexToUpdate!-1] = {
          ...newFiles[indexToUpdate!-1],
          active: true
        };
      } else {
        if (openedFiles.length > 1) {
          newFiles[indexToUpdate!+1] = {
            ...newFiles[indexToUpdate!+1],
            active: true
          };
        }
      }

      return [...newFiles];
    });
  };

  const selectTab = (tabIndex: number) => {
    setFiles((currentFiles: IdeFile[]) => {
      const newFiles = currentFiles.map((element, index) => {
        if (tabIndex === index) {
          return {
            ...element,
            active: true
          };
        } else {
          return {
            ...element,
            active: false
          };
        }
      });

      return [...newFiles];
    });
  };

  const ctxValue = {
    files,
    openedFiles,
    selectFileHandler,
    openFileInTab,
    closeTab,
    selectTab
  };

  return <IdeEmulatorContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>
    {children}
  </IdeEmulatorContext.Provider>
};
```

**tabs-list.tsx**

```
const TabsList = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(IdeEmulatorContext);

  const closeHandler = (name: string) => {
    ctx.closeTab(name)
  }

  return <nav className="nav-bar">
    <ol className="tabs">
      {ctx.openedFiles.map((element: IdeFile, index: number) => <li key={element.name} className={element.active ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => ctx.selectTab(index)}>
        {element.name} {element.active ? <button className="btn-close" onClick={() => closeHandler(element.name)}>x</button> : null}
      </li>)}
    </ol>
  </nav>
};
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because of the **bubbling** of the **close click event**. Let me break down what's happening:

- You click the `tab element` which updates the state and set the `active` flag to true
- Now, you `close` the element by clicking on the **X** button. This action triggers two function: `closeHandler` and `ctx.selectTab` for the element. The trigger to `ctx.selectTab` is caused by the *click* on the button getting propagated to the parent (which is known as [**event bubbling**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/event-bubbling-in-javascript/)).

To prevent this, you need stop the *event propagation*. This is how you can achieve this:

```js
const closeHandler = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, name: string) => {
     event.stopPropagation();
     ctx.closeTab(name);
}

//....
onClick={(e) => closeHandler(e, element.name)}
```

**Edit (Just an advice, not much related with the actual issue) :** Another issue I noticed with your logic is that you are passing `index` as an identifier in the `ctx.selectTab(index)`. This will give you unwanted bugs whenever the item in `openedFiles` will be changed. To prevent this, use something that will be actually unique, such as `name`, `tabId`.

Hope this helps :)